# Галлерея плиткой как на примере. По какому запросу подходящий плагин искать?

Tags: jquery, изображения, gallery, lightbox

Галлерея плиткой как на примере. 
[image: Пример]
Какой плагин может подойти?
По какому запросу подходящий плагин можно искать?

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, [masonry](//masonry.desandro.com/) может подойти.

Comment: Увы, у Masonry нет такого функционала

Answer (score 0):

можно [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) попробовать, хотя я не знаю, можно ли сделать там так с первой картинкой.

Comment: Всегда думал, что он просто каруселька...